# How define Next js Context types in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I need to know how to define next js `Context` types and and it's `req` types?

Here I write this `getServerSideProps` function-

```
//Server side functions
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    await getMovies(context, context.req);
    return { props: {} }
}
```

And here I write this function-

```
export const getMovies = (context: **types, req: **types) => {
    //here the main function
}
```

Here How Can I define `context` types and `req` types?

Please help me?

Answer (score 7):

In VS Code, you can right click on a type and click "Go to Definition". The type of `GetServerSideProps` is defined inside next.js as:

```
export type GetServerSideProps<
  P extends { [key: string]: any } = { [key: string]: any },
  Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery,
  D extends PreviewData = PreviewData
> = (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext<Q, D>
) => Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<P>>
```

So it looks like the `context` parameter is a `GetServerSidePropsContext`, with some generic parameters.

Which means your function becomes:

```
import type {
  GetServerSideProps,
  GetServerSidePropsContext,
  PreviewData,
} from "next";
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from "querystring";

// ...

export function getMovies<Q extends ParsedUrlQuery, D extends PreviewData>(
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext<Q, D>,
  req: GetServerSidePropsContext<Q, D>["req"]
) {
  // ...
}
```

I would just drop the `req` parameter though, it's already in `context`. Extract it inside `getMovies` if you must.